# Early return of results in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is is possible to get elasticsearch to terminate its search early and just return the first N matches it finds?

I have a large data set and have noticed that when I issue a query that hits all the records, it takes much longer to return the top 10 results than if the query hits only a small number of results.  I don't really need the full result count, and I don't care whether the 10 results returned are the "best" matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to setting the size as in Richa's answer, you might also want to check the two [following request parameters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html), namely:

- `timeout`: allows you to specify a maximum execution time (in milliseconds). ES will respond as soon as that timeout is reached and return the results it got so far.
- `terminate_after`: the maximum number of docs to get in each shard

Comment: I think this is probably the answer, though surprisingly terminate_after does not help performance as much as I would have thought, but it probably has something to do with the query being cached (or the index files being cached by the OS) from having run it before.

Comment: If you have 5 shards (default settings) and want 5 hits in your response, you might want to try `terminate_after=1` and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `size`

```
GET /index/type/_search?size=5
```

Comment: This has no effect (for me anyway) on the amount of time taken to return.  The "size" specifies the number of results returned, but elasticsearch still reports the complete hitcount (the number of available matches) which I think means that it is actually still searching the whole database and not stopping with the first 5 found.